What would happen to a system of two identical charges one with velocity $v$ and other at rest given unlimited time?
Two identical charged particles one having velocity $v$ and other starts from rest along a straight line. What would happen given an unlimited time?
I think the charge initially at rest should keep on accelerating with acceleration reducing and the other charge would first come at rest and then accelerate in the opposite direction. The net momentum of the system would also be conserved along with mechanical energy.
Am I right?

"The net momentum of the system would also be conserved along with mechanical energy" Not really. Electromagnetic fields carry energy and momentum and their contribution has to be taken into account to get the right conservation laws.

What happens would depend on the magnitude of the 2 charges, their masses and their proximity. Two electrons 1 lightyear apart would have no measurable effect each other. An electron flying close to a proton will be strongly deflected. Please provide more details.

If the charges are identical, why would the moving charge reverse direction of motion? When a moving billiard ball impacts head-on with a ball at rest, the moving ball will stop, it will not start moving in the opposite direction.

Why would the acceleration of the charged particle that is initially at rest be reducing? If the moving particle approaches, its electric field acting on the particle initially at rest would increase.

@JánLalinský They are not colliding. Electrostatic force of repulsion won't let them collide

They repel each other, right? That is like collision.

If the two particles are equal mass, the moving particle starts with velocity V from a long distance, is approaching the stationary particle, and if we ignore radiation, I think @JánLalinský is correct that this would be like a drawn out version of colliding billiard balls.  The initially stationary particle would approach a velocity V, and the other particle would approach 0 velocity.
